# Who chose the examples in the tour, and shouldn't they be changed?

Tags: discussion

I just went and looked at [the tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) for the first time in years.

This is faulty.   The tour is explaining that

> This site is all about getting answers. It’s not a discussion forum. There’s no chit-chat.

The example question is “Who would command Enterprise D…”

And then it goes ahead with the example answers that start with ***I would say…*** and ***Presumably, …***

Basically the examples are expressing opinions and inviting discussion.

## Isn’t this exactly the wrong example to set?   Where did this come from?  Shouldn’t we change the examples?

Comment: I'm about 73% sure that the example question changes, mayhaps randomly at some given interval.

Comment: The example answers, while not extraordinary, aren’t really discussion. Just starting with wish-washy language doesn’t make something an opinion (though these are not well-cited).

Comment: You may be interested in [What determines the questions available for selection in the about-page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163947/252593)

Comment: I agree that the question and answers are not good examples of what we hope to see on this site. Part of the problem is that the screen format in the tour requires very short questions and answers. It would be hard (but surely not impossible) to come up with a good question and a couple of answers that will fit in the available space.

Comment: @blackwood SEDE query with well received question/answer pair, recent, and with a short body. Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Don't forget there's only a finite list we can choose from!

Answer (score 8):

I don't know who chose the current example, but I just discovered (thanks to [Mooz's comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10108/who-chose-the-examples-in-the-tour-and-shouldnt-they-be-changed#comment29287_10108)) that site moderators can change it to any other question satisfying certain criteria, of which there are currently **150**. Of these, the ones which have accepted answers are:

- [Who would command the Enterprise D if the ranking officers were off the ship?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117274/who-would-command-the-enterprise-d-if-the-ranking-officers-were-off-the-ship)
- [Why does Kylo Ren wear a mask?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111174/why-does-kylo-ren-wear-a-mask)
- [Why didn't Yoda have any children to take care of him during his last days given that he lived up to 900 years old?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110875/why-didnt-yoda-have-any-children-to-take-care-of-him-during-his-last-days-given)
- [Can an astromech droids control and fly the ships they're mounted in?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110592/can-astromech-droids-control-and-fly-the-ships-theyre-mounted-in)
- [Why does Sauron fear Aragorn if he is a Maia?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108212/why-does-sauron-fear-aragorn-if-he-is-a-maia)
- [Actors appearing in both Star Trek and Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105236/actors-appearing-in-both-star-trek-and-star-wars)
- [Novel about a parasite/symbiote that causes immortality](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94854/novel-about-a-parasite-symbiote-that-causes-immortality)
- [Where did the Iron Man suits come from in Age of Ultron?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89280/where-did-the-iron-man-suits-come-from-in-age-of-ultron)
- [Why were the "Monsters, Inc." monsters told that touching kids would kill them?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69138/why-were-the-monsters-inc-monsters-told-that-touching-kids-would-kill-them)
- [Why would Snape still be well informed about Order plans?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67170/why-would-snape-still-be-well-informed-about-order-plans)
- [Is Daenerys Targaryen capable of conceiving a child?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60198/is-daenerys-targaryen-capable-of-conceiving-a-child)
- [Which individual Superhero role has been portrayed by the highest number of individuals?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56912/which-individual-superhero-role-has-been-portrayed-by-the-highest-number-of-indi)
- [Was the significance of Arya's Braavosi coin ever explained?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56218/was-the-significance-of-aryas-braavosi-coin-ever-explained)
- [What is the name of the TNG episode focusing on crew members below command level?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51873/what-is-the-name-of-the-tng-episode-focusing-on-crew-members-below-command-level)
- [How many regenerations does the Doctor have after The Time of the Doctor?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46879/how-many-regenerations-does-the-doctor-have-after-the-time-of-the-doctor)
- [Why is no mutant from X-men series a member of S.H.I.E.L.D?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42876/why-is-no-mutant-from-x-men-series-a-member-of-s-h-i-e-l-d)
- [What material is Thor's hammer made of?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42629/what-material-is-thors-hammer-made-of)
- [How could Argus Filch clean up the whole castle by himself without magic?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40228/how-could-argus-filch-clean-up-the-whole-castle-by-himself-without-magic)
- [Why does the computer have a human female voice?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39133/why-does-the-computer-have-a-human-female-voice)
- [Don't the cities ever employ mass transit on 1st World planets in the Star Wars Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34165/dont-the-cities-ever-employ-mass-transit-on-1st-world-planets-in-the-star-wars)
- [Who exactly was Hagrid expecting in the Chamber of Secrets?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33531/who-exactly-was-hagrid-expecting-in-the-chamber-of-secrets)
- [How can the Xenomorph see?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31648/how-can-the-xenomorph-see)
- [How can Galadriel go into the West?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28559/how-can-galadriel-go-into-the-west)
- [Which book/film ended this way?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27354/which-book-film-ended-this-way)
- [Are there real-world Recipes for Middle Earth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27184/are-there-real-world-recipes-for-middle-earth)
- [Why was Arthur Dent surprised by Slartibartfast's name?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23614/why-was-arthur-dent-surprised-by-slartibartfasts-name)
- [How do you make a combine soldier?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23406/how-do-you-make-a-combine-soldier)
- [What happens to the people inside when the TARDIS is tilted?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23276/what-happens-to-the-people-inside-when-the-tardis-is-tilted)
- [Why wasn't Superman naked when he was lifting Luthor's artificial continent?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22723/why-wasnt-superman-naked-when-he-was-lifting-luthors-artificial-continent)
- [Where does Gandalf Live?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22334/where-does-gandalf-live)
- [Which work of Scifi/fantasy was the first to depict a person as a hologram?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22146/which-work-of-scifi-fantasy-was-the-first-to-depict-a-person-as-a-hologram)
- [Can hybrid Vulcan/Humans procreate, or are they like mules?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21991/can-hybrid-vulcan-humans-procreate-or-are-they-like-mules)
- [Did JRR Tolkien ever write any music for the many songs in The Lord of the Rings?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21376/did-jrr-tolkien-ever-write-any-music-for-the-many-songs-in-the-lord-of-the-rings)
- [What did the people in the prison chant in The Dark Knight Rises?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21275/what-did-the-people-in-the-prison-chant-in-the-dark-knight-rises)
- [Who was the first DC/Marvel costumed crime fighter credited as being a former Olympic athlete?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21155/who-was-the-first-dc-marvel-costumed-crime-fighter-credited-as-being-a-former-ol)
- [Why does Bender need to sleep?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20663/why-does-bender-need-to-sleep)
- [Why didn't Loki's staff work on Tony Stark?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20276/why-didnt-lokis-staff-work-on-tony-stark)
- [Is the Simpsons a cartoon or live-action show in the Futurama universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19706/is-the-simpsons-a-cartoon-or-live-action-show-in-the-futurama-universe)
- [Trying to find the title of an old movie about a robot like WALL-E](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18670/trying-to-find-the-title-of-an-old-movie-about-a-robot-like-wall-e)
- [Did Darwin die or survive when Sebastion Shaw put energy in his mouth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18176/did-darwin-die-or-survive-when-sebastion-shaw-put-energy-in-his-mouth)
- [Why do the Walking Dead zombies stop decomposing?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18033/why-do-the-walking-dead-zombies-stop-decomposing)
- [How did the Basilisk survive for a thousand years?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16691/how-did-the-basilisk-survive-for-a-thousand-years)
- [Why was Captain America called "The First Avenger"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16066/why-was-captain-america-called-the-first-avenger)
- [How long does it take for dragons to grow?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15926/how-long-does-it-take-for-dragons-to-grow)
- [Why is Petyr Baelish called "Littlefinger"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14629/why-is-petyr-baelish-called-littlefinger)
- [When is the Grand Galloping Gala?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14605/when-is-the-grand-galloping-gala)
- [What purpose does acidic blood serve to a Xenomorph?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13673/what-purpose-does-acidic-blood-serve-to-a-xenomorph)
- [Why didn't Saruman take Narya from Gandalf?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12812/why-didnt-saruman-take-narya-from-gandalf)
- [Why didn't they order Spock to perform the Vulcan "Mind Meld" on Captian Pike?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12741/why-didnt-they-order-spock-to-perform-the-vulcan-mind-meld-on-captian-pike)
- [Why was Gandalf afraid of the Balrog of Morgoth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12448/why-was-gandalf-afraid-of-the-balrog-of-morgoth)
- [How are Sith names picked?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12264/how-are-sith-names-picked)
- [Were there ever any "good" Orcs?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11859/were-there-ever-any-good-orcs)
- [Is R'hllor, The Lord of Light, the only "real" god?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11787/is-rhllor-the-lord-of-light-the-only-real-god)
- [In The Walking Dead, what happens to zombies that don't eat?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11332/in-the-walking-dead-what-happens-to-zombies-that-dont-eat)
- [Why was the Superman's symbol an *English* letter "S"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11079/why-was-the-supermans-symbol-an-english-letter-s)
- [What's the origin of "One does not simply Telnet into Mordor"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10952/whats-the-origin-of-one-does-not-simply-telnet-into-mordor)
- [When (in which year) is Alien set?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10825/when-in-which-year-is-alien-set)
- [What Is the First Same Sex Relationship in Science Fiction?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10788/what-is-the-first-same-sex-relationship-in-science-fiction)
- [Who gets Muggle-born students onto Platform 9 3/4?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10274/who-gets-muggle-born-students-onto-platform-9-3-4)
- [Do Non-Jedi (and Non-Sith) Use Lightsabers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9874/do-non-jedi-and-non-sith-use-lightsabers)
- [What are the creatures in I Am Legend?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8142/what-are-the-creatures-in-i-am-legend)
- [Which Actors Were Featured in Both Star Wars Trilogies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7881/which-actors-were-featured-in-both-star-wars-trilogies)
- [When did the Sith enter the star wars canon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7529/when-did-the-sith-enter-the-star-wars-canon)
- [If Worf was raised by humans after the age of 5, why does he "act" so Klingon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6700/if-worf-was-raised-by-humans-after-the-age-of-5-why-does-he-act-so-klingon)
- [Effects/Corruption of the One Ring on Smeagol](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6585/effects-corruption-of-the-one-ring-on-smeagol)
- [Why didn't they make a new TNG movie after Nemesis?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6071/why-didnt-they-make-a-new-tng-movie-after-nemesis)
- [How did Luke further his training after the Empire's defeat?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5815/how-did-luke-further-his-training-after-the-empires-defeat)
- [Why did the Borg name Locutus?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/why-did-the-borg-name-locutus)
- [Who are Species 125?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4912/who-are-species-125)
- [What's the real world equivalent for the greyscale disease?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4883/whats-the-real-world-equivalent-for-the-greyscale-disease)
- [Why did Harry Potter break the Elder Wand?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4805/why-did-harry-potter-break-the-elder-wand)
- [What are all of Harry Dresden's foci?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/what-are-all-of-harry-dresdens-foci)
- [When did Arya take The Hound out of her prayer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4657/when-did-arya-take-the-hound-out-of-her-prayer)
- [Have any movies been based on Isaac Asimov's Foundation Series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4532/have-any-movies-been-based-on-isaac-asimovs-foundation-series)
- [Why can't muggles see magical creatures?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4352/why-cant-muggles-see-magical-creatures)
- [Earth in a timestorm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4330/earth-in-a-timestorm)
- [What does an arakh look like?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3870/what-does-an-arakh-look-like)
- [Were Renly and Loras really in a relationship?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3863/renly-and-loras-really)
- [What real-world substance most closely corresponds to mithril?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/what-real-world-substance-most-closely-corresponds-to-mithril)
- [Why do Jawas always wear hoods? Even indoors. What do they look like?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/why-do-jawas-always-wear-hoods-even-indoors-what-do-they-look-like)
- [In Dune, how do they communicate between planets?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3647/in-dune-how-do-they-communicate-between-planets)
- [Why did Tyrion visit the Wall?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3577/why-did-tyrion-visit-the-wall)
- [Does the intro sequence to the Game of Thrones TV series have any meaning?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3556/does-the-intro-sequence-to-the-game-of-thrones-tv-series-have-any-meaning)
- [Number of Jedi after Order 66?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/number-of-jedi-after-order-66)
- [Invisibility Cloak - overrated much?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/invisibility-cloak-overrated-much)
- [Was the thermal exhaust port on the Death Star really a design flaw?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/was-the-thermal-exhaust-port-on-the-death-star-really-a-design-flaw)
- [Explanation of seasons in "A Song of Ice and Fire"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/explanation-of-seasons-in-a-song-of-ice-and-fire)
- [How did Gared (Night's Watch man) get back from behind The Wall?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/how-did-the-black-brother-get-back-from-behind-the-wall)
- [What is a Hedge Knight?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2925/what-is-a-hedge-knight)
- [Why does Leia's accent change during A New Hope?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/why-does-leias-accent-change-during-a-new-hope)
- [What plot differences are there between the Game of Thrones TV series and the books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/what-plot-differences-are-there-between-the-game-of-thrones-tv-series-and-the-bo)
- [What Sci-Fi novel is about aliens who consider it simply convenient to exterminate the human race?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/what-sci-fi-novel-is-about-aliens-who-consider-it-simply-convenient-to-extermina)
- [What order should Asimov's Foundation series be read in?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/what-order-should-asimovs-foundation-series-be-read-in)
- [What makes the world so oblivious to Clark Kent's secret?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2205/what-makes-the-world-so-oblivious-to-clark-kents-secret)
- [In Niven's Known Space, what currency are the Outsiders interested in?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2171/in-nivens-known-space-what-currency-are-the-outsiders-interested-in)
- [Why do the guns in Battlestar Galactica have two barrels?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2165/why-do-the-guns-in-battlestar-galactica-have-two-barrels)
- [Why and how can you hear explosions in space in Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/why-and-how-can-you-hear-explosions-in-space-in-star-wars)
- [How does the holodeck create the illusion of distance?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1802/how-does-the-holodeck-create-the-illusion-of-distance)
- [Who or what was Tom Bombadil?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/who-or-what-was-tom-bombadil)
- [Who invented or theorized the replicator?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1123/who-invented-or-theorized-the-replicator)
- [Was "Worf" from Star Trek: The Next Generation an afterthought?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1036/was-worf-from-star-trek-the-next-generation-an-afterthought)
- [Given the multiple defeats at the hands of the Federation, why only one Borg Cube?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/887/given-the-multiple-defeats-at-the-hands-of-the-federation-why-only-one-borg-cub)
- [Asimov - Start with Foundation or Robots](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/832/asimov-start-with-foundation-or-robots)
- [Is it true that The Doctor can only regenerate 12 times?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/809/is-it-true-that-the-doctor-can-only-regenerate-12-times)
- [How did the Skylark deal with the Einstein light-speed limit?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/648/how-did-the-skylark-deal-with-the-einstein-light-speed-limit)
- [What was the robot's name in "Lost in Space"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-was-the-robots-name-in-lost-in-space)
- [What was Asimov's contribution to real-world robotics?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/587/what-was-asimovs-contribution-to-real-world-robotics)
- [Are The Three Laws of Robotics explicitly defined in one of the Asimov's stories?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/581/are-the-three-laws-of-robotics-explicitly-defined-in-one-of-the-asimovs-stories)
- [How is the universal translator device in Star Trek supposed to work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-is-the-universal-translator-device-in-star-trek-supposed-to-work)
- [What was Shepherd Book's past in Firefly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-was-shepherd-books-past-in-firefly)
- [In the Dune series, why are they not using computers and programming related technologies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164/in-the-dune-series-why-are-they-not-using-computers-and-programming-related-tec)
- [Who is the inventor of cyberpunk?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/88/who-is-the-inventor-of-cyberpunk)
- [When did Obi-Wan Kenobi learn that Anakin was "dead"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55/when-did-obi-wan-kenobi-learn-that-anakin-was-dead)
- [How many different Enterprises were there?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15/how-many-different-enterprises-were-there)
- [What was the catastrophe that happened in "The Road"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8/what-was-the-catastrophe-that-happened-in-the-road)
- [Why didn't Nero visit his homeworld to warn of its destruction?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6/why-didnt-nero-visit-his-homeworld-to-warn-of-its-destruction)

Take your pick! If there's enough consensus in favour of changing the example question to a particular one of these, we can do it with a single press of a button.

Comment: Personally I don't think a story-ID question would be a good pick. If possible, it would be nice to choose something that appeals to more than one fandom (e.g. not just a plain Star Trek question or a plain Harry Potter question).

Comment: If you avoid overly specific plot-explanation questions, there's no problem with single-fandom stuff. Everyone knows what Harry Potter is, even if they never read/watched it. And maybe try to avoid stuff like *"about the season 5 finale of GoT"* or *"Why did Kylo Ren do that to this character"* for avoiding lynch mobs.

Comment: I haven't reviewed all of them, but how about [How does the holodeck create the illusion of distance?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1802/how-does-the-holodeck-create-the-illusion-of-distance). Stripped of the comments, the question and the first two answers would probably fit.

Comment: This one would probably make a good example; Simple, direct, etc http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-was-the-robots-name-in-lost-in-space

Comment: @Valorum I'd like to see a question which is interesting to as wide an audience as possible, and I haven't even heard of this "Lost in Space" thing. (Admittedly I live under a rock, but ...)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - It ran for about forty years in syndication and spawned a hit film starring Oscar-winners William Hurt and Gary Oldman

Answer (score 3):

From the [list of qualifying questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10109/20774) provided by Rand, I believe that we should be using this question for the tour example;

**[What was the robot's name in "Lost in Space"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-was-the-robots-name-in-lost-in-space)**

The question is clear, concise and short. The answer/s are clear, concise and short with a linked reference.

Additionally, Lost in Space is desirable (as a tag) because it's a universally  recognised property, having run for more than 50 years in syndication, but not one that raises polarising views.

---

[image]

Comment: I don't know.   The second answer there is still too chatty, IMO.

Comment: Sorry, -1. "*The question is clear, concise and short. The answer/s are clear, concise and short*" applies to all the questions on the list (it's basically the criterion that defines the list), and Lost in Space is surely less universally recognisable than e.g. Star Wars, Star Trek, Harry Potter, Lord of the Rings, or Game of Thrones.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - It's a reasonable answer though. Maybe before we post it as the sample answer we could tidy up the language a little

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I was thinking that instead of going for something that might put people off (e.g. Star Wars vs. Star Trek) we should go for something that's pretty much universally popular

Comment: @Valorum:  I don't know about universally popular.   More likely universally indifferent.   I have never seen Lost in Space and I think that's probably true of a huge fraction of sff.se.    I would suggest something related to ***Superman*** to be be universally known (and popular, in general).

Comment: @ThePopMachine - You've never seen Lost in Space? Get on the donkey.

Comment: @Valorum How about something that appeals to *both* SW and ST fans? I would've suggested [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105236/actors-appearing-in-both-star-trek-and-star-wars) already if not for the obvious conflict of interest ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Well that was the other thing I was trying to avoid, something that's been answered by a mod or someone in the top 10

Comment: @Randal'Thor:   I think that's a good question for this.

Comment: @Valorum  - **are** there any questions not answered by you at all? :)

Comment: @dvk-in-Exile - anything Game of Thrones, anything with "Super Saiyan" in the title.

Comment: Some of the * ahem * Tolkien questions? Not that I have any interest in those at all.

Comment: @mattgutting - Feel free to propose another :-)