# Selecting an example for the Tour page's example question

Tags: discussion

It would appear that at some point in time the [Tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) lost its example question: it somehow has become ineligible and so has defaulted to the default unicorn example. Now, whilst the default is actually somewhat on topic for us it isn't a good example of a question we want to show new users so we should probably update it.

[Last time](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10108/58193) this came up a list of questions was given to pick from. This list comes from [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/92078/possible-about-questions) of question that should be eligible to pick for the Tour that was shared on the [main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163948/345161) asking what can be chosen for it.

So can we decide on a new question to show on the Tour page?

Comment: Actually, no, the list you linked to didn't come from an SEDE query: it came from me looking at the list on [this mod-only page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/admin/about/choose-question) and painstakingly copying the links one by one. Just saying :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor That's clearly a made up page, just 404s!

Comment: Also the list is longer now: currently 192 possible eligible questions. (IIRC, the linked SEDE query isn't *exactly* accurate, and may not get the list exactly right for some reason.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor The SEDE query turns up 192 at the moment so it may be correct for us at the moment.

Comment: The key thing to know is that the Tour page can only show Q&A with no formatting. That means it will show, not necessarily the accepted answer, but two answers which are **short, with no quote blocks, no spoiler blocks, possibly even no links or headers/bold text**. If you can find any such answers which are actually *good* by our site's standards, then I applaud you.

Comment: Looking through WayBackMachine records, it seems that the question being used for the tour was deleted around August-October 2019, and so the system reverted the tour back to the generic question at that time.

Comment: Related: On MSE I suggested that [moderators be notified when the tour reverts to the unicorn question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351469/323179). If I’m reading the comments right, the tour has been like this for almost a year :/

Comment: @Laurel seems to be, I noticed it a few weeks back but just got around to posting this meta. Good idea for a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

I've had another look through the list of questions and I think this [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium) one is quite good:

## [Why did the Nazgul start on horseback?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8284/58193)

The answers are pretty decent to say they don't have the supporting quotes in which they can't have. It seems to me to be accurate and well written and if someone was to click through and find the question it does have a good answer with quotes.

Comment: I had to delete my answer (which had actually gathered a good consensus) because somehow that question became ineligible. This one isn't bad, but I prefer [How can Galadriel go into the West?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/28559/31394) because the two short Tour-eligible answers actually have sources, just not blockquotes. I'm going to edit the answers and add a note asking people *not* to edit in quotes just this once, then make an executive decision and stick it in the Tour.